# How to add a nested element in a model in Elm

Tags: record, elm

Is there a standard way to do the following?

```
{ model | country =
  { model.country | state =
    { model.country.state | city =
      { model.country.state.city | people =
        model.country.state.city.people ++ [ newPerson ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, `country`, `state`, and `city` are records nested in the `model`. I just want to add a person in the nested `city` record.

The above doesn't actually work. I get the following error on the first mention of `model.country`:

> I am looking for one of the following things:
>
> ```
> "'"
> "|"
> an equals sign '='
> more letters in this name
> whitespace
> ```

The way I was able to get this to work was to simply call a function at each step:

```
{ model | country = updateCountry newPerson model.country }

updateCountry person country =
  { country | state = updateState newPerson country.state }
```

And then the same for `updateState` and `updateCity`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today(`0.18.0`), arbitrary expressions are not allowed in record update syntax.

In other words, you can not access field of a record during the update:

```elm
model = { model.topProperty | childProperty = "Hello" }
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            Syntax error
```

It is a [planned feature](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/537) for Elm Compiler, but for now, you should consider restructuring your model or using one of the verbose workarounds.

Personally, I prefer `let..in` expression for that, but I never use records with depth, higher than 3.

#### `let..in` example

It looks super-verbose, but there is nothing bad with this approach. You will be abe to refactor it when Elm Compiler will support a better syntax.

Use this as a starting point for developing a set of helper functions for updates of different levels.

```elm
let
    -- Deconstruct on every level.
    { model } = init
    { country } = model
    { state } = country
    { city } = state
    { people } = city
in
    { init
        | model =
            { model
                | country =
                    { country
                        | state =
                            { state
                                | city =
                                    { city
                                        | people = "John" :: people
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is usually better to make the record structure flatter if you want to do stuff like this.
Typically:

- nested records are OK if your manipulation is also nested: if you do have a separate updating function for each level. And/or if you only want to update the nested record at its own level.
- if you need root level access to some nested record, then flat is better.

What I tend to do is store everything at root level, and include IDs for reference. For your example this would look something like this:

```
type alias Model =
  { persons : Dict PersonID Person
  , cities : Dict CityID City
  , states : Dict StateID State
  , countries : Dict CountryID Country
  }
```

This structure allows you full access from root level to all entities.
So adding a person would be:

```
  { model 
  | persons =
      model.persons
      |> Dict.insert newPersonID newPerson
  }
```

To get all cities in a country would be a bit more work now BTW:

```
citiesInCountry : Model -> CountryID -> Dict CityID City
citiesInCountry model countryID = 
    let
      statesInCountry =
        model.states
        |> Dict.filter (\id state -> state.countryID == countryID)
    in
      model.cities
      |> Dict.filter (\id city -> Dict.member city.stateID statesInCountry)
```

So it kind of depends which operation is more frequent in your app:

- if you have a lot of operations like "get all grandchildren", then the nested approach could be better
- if you have a lot of "update this grandchild", then the flat alternative might be better suited

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/evancz/focus but note the small print. Could you work with a different data structure instead, such as

```
Dict ( String, String, String ) Int
```

Then

```
addOne country state city = 
  Dict.update (country, state, city) 
     (\v -> case v of 
               Just v_ -> v_ + 1
               Nothing -> 1)
     database
```

Comment: The focus library looks like what I was hoping for.. interesting comment by Evan, "I have yet to see any code that follows The Elm Architecture that gets better by adding this library." Hasn't been updated for Elm 0.18 yet. Maybe it's not a priority given the noted problems. Regarding `Dict`, I'd have to rethink my model as I have many different types of data at each level.